# aws cognito-idp list-users : filter by email domain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I can filter on addresses that start with "john@"

```
aws cognito-idp list-users --user-pool-id my-pool --filter "email ^= \"john@\"" --limit 20
```

Is it possible to filter on ends with "@gmail.com"?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.

If you use the `--query` instead of `--filter` you can query on anything in the resulting response by using [JMESPath](https://jmespath.org/specification.html).

So to filter out `@gmail.com` you can do:

```bash
aws cognito-idp list-users --user-pool-id my-pool --query 'Users[?Attributes[?Name==`email` && contains(Value, `gmail.com`)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not at the moment. You can follow this issue to see if in the future they add this feature: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/3136

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31234049)